# CKEditor 4.6 Image upload does not insert image URL after upload

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, ckeditor

So on my server I have a php upload script that does the work. From CKEditor I set the path to it and the file browser location. When I select a file and click "Send to server" all works, image is uploaded, the script returns the desired JSON as per the documentation. Example: `{"uploaded":1,"fileName":"18_logo[dot]png.png","url":"http:\/\/mylocalhosturl.com\/courses_data\/course_380\/images\/18_logo[dot]png.png"}`
URL is valid. I copy it and the image can be opened. I can also insert it manually in the Image Info -> URL field and it gets inserted in the editor, but I think this should happen automatically and it does not! I get this JSON response in the same place I add the image file. 
Here is my CKEDITOR configuration for the upload request:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'topic_editor', {

            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '<?php echo URL::base();?><?php echo $current_school;?>/topic/uploadImage/<?php echo 'course_'.$course_id; ?>',
            filebrowserBrowseUrl: '<?php echo URL::base();?><?php echo str_replace("\\","/",$courseDir);?>',
            filebrowserUploadUrl: '<?php echo URL::base();?><?php echo str_replace("\\","/",$courseDir);?>'

        });
        CKEDITOR.instances.topic_editor.setData('<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($topicData['content']);?>', function () {
            this.checkDirty();
        });
```

Do I need to add anything so that after upload, the uploaded image gets inserted? The documentation is not clear on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself. The documentation is poorly written. The response that is expected is this: `<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, $url, $message);</script>`
After changing my JSON to an echo with this html with proper url and funcNum data, everything works. Hope this helps someone.